# Fabric.js add images order

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to add images to canvas strictly, but images are added randomly.

What's the problem?

Here is my simple code.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("preview");
var imgs = ['bgBottom','bgTop', 'bgLevel', 'bgCircle'];
for (var i=0; i<imgs.length;i++){
            var url = imgs[i]+'.png';
                    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (oImg) {
                        canvas.add(oImg)
                    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fabric.Image.fromURL` loads the image in the background and runs the anonymous function you pass to it once image load is complete which adds it to the canvas.  The order that the browser loads the images will vary and you can't rely on it being in a specific order.

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0wLgwhw/) that shows loading an array of images and making sure they're displayed in a set order. This works by adding the image to the canvas before it's loaded; it just doesn't render until the image is available to be displayed.

The code from the jsfiddle:

```
var SelfLoadingImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
    initialize: function(src) {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = src;
        this.image.onload = (function() {
            this.width = this.image.width;
            this.height = this.image.height;
            this.loaded = true;
            this.setCoords();
            this.fire('image:loaded');
            canvas.renderAll();
        }).bind(this);
    },

    _render: function(ctx)
    {
        if (this.loaded) {
            ctx.drawImage(this.image, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);
        }
    }
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("preview");
var imgs = [
    'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/ifunny/128/dog-icon.png', // dog
    'http://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_14ee6ada72a4_128.png', // cat
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bc/Nuvola_devices_mouse.png' // mouse
];

for (var i=0; i<imgs.length;i++){
    var url = imgs[i];
    var img = new SelfLoadingImage(url);
    canvas.add(img);
}
```